# Can't create valid nested array with table properties (Vanilla JS)

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom, multidimensional-array, html-table

I try to make a game - "Cross and circle".
I want that after every click put a value in an empty nested array by the click location.

This is the relevant code:

```js
let table = document.getElementById("table");
let counter = 0;
let arr = [
  [],
  []
];
let win = 0;


table.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  let r = parseInt(e.target.parentElement.rowIndex);
  let c = parseInt(e.target.cellIndex);

  if (counter % 2 == 0) {
    e.target.classList.add("cross");
    arr[c][r] = 1;
  } else {
    e.target.classList.add("cricle");
    arr[c][r] = 2;
  }

  counter++;
  
  console.log(arr);
})
```

```css
#table { border-collapse: collapse; }
td { padding: 20px; border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

- If you click on col: 0, row: 0 - In the array it will be in location "1,0" for some reason. It's counting it wrong no matter what cell you click on.
- If you click on col number 3, always this error will occur: "Cannot set property '0' of undefined
  at HTMLTableElement".

This how the table looks like:
https://i.imagesup.co/images2/912bc616f03df0e6a75509d7ce36b17e1a2fbbfb.png

Thank you very much for help !

Comment: Your `arr` only has *two* child arrays, but your table has *three* columns. Also, it seems to work fine otherwise - I can't replicate the first error you mentioned.

Comment: I've edited your question to include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). To do so, I had to add two lines of CSS and a `console.log()`. While I don't think this compromises the code or changes the question, if you disagree, feel free to roll back my edit.

Comment: @TylerRoper Hey, thanks for the answer. Do you know how can I create a "big" nested array, like 1000x1500 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define an array with `let arr = [[],[]];` here.
Then you set a value by using `arr[c][r] = 1;` or `arr[c][r] = 2;`

So, when clicking on column 3, you want to assign something to `arr[2][r]...`.
In this case your array does only have a length of 2. (`[[],[]]`)
(`arr[0][r]` and `arr[1][r]` are working...)

So  `arr[2][r]` is undefined.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. Do you know how can I create a "big" nested array, like 1000x1500 ?

Comment: @lirsim You could use ````let b = Array(1000); b.fill([],0,1000);```` for example.